# jqgrid dosnt show data,it's work fine in localhost but not in my server

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, json, jqgrid

ihave a trouble with jqgrid in php, fist of all i should say, every thing ok in my localhost,everyhing work fin but in my server it doesn't
jqgrid doesnt display data, i checked the php file and js file , the js send data to php, and php select my need data right , but somthing happened, the php file doesnt has errors , and fill $response right, and then echo json_encode($response);.....i guess the problem is here, when php file want send data to script...i dont know really....please help me... there is the code
the js file :

```
    <script type='text/javascript'>
        jQuery('document').ready(function() {
            var id = $userId;
            jQuery('#users').jqGrid({
                url:'../includes/ProductHistory/process.php?id='+id,
                datatype: 'json',
                mtype: 'GET',
                direction:'rtl',
                height: 'auto',
                width: '530',
                colNames:['pic ','pname','pdate', 'price'],
                colModel:[
                 {name:'file_url',index:'file_url', width:40 , sortable:false , search:false , edittype: 'image', formatter: imageFormatter},
                 {name:'product_name',index:'product_name', width:65},
                 {name:'created_on',index:'created_on', width:70 ,search:false},
                 {name:'product_final_price',index:'product_final_price', width:60 , sorttype:'number'}
                ],
                rowNum:10,
                rowTotal: 2000,
                rowList : [10,20,30,50],
                rownumbers: true,
                rownumWidth: 15,
                gridview: true,
                pager: '#usersPage',
                sortname: 'created_on',
                viewrecords: true,
                sortorder: 'desc',
                caption: 'products'   
            });


            jQuery('#users').jqGrid('navGrid','#usersPage',
                {
                    edit:false,add:false,del:false,search:false,refresh:true
                },
                {}, // edit options
                {}, // add options
                {}, //del options
                {} // search options
                );
            jQuery('#users').jqGrid('filterToolbar',{stringResult: true,searchOnEnter : false});


        });
        function imageFormatter(cellvalue, options, rowObject) {

        return '<img src= ../' + cellvalue + ' height=80 width=80 />';

        };

    </script>
```

and this is the php file :

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
$response->rows[$i]['product_name']   = $row['product_name'];   
$response->rows[$i]['cell'] = array($row['file_url'],$row['product_name'],$row['created_on'],$row['product_final_price']);
$i++;}
 echo json_encode($response);
```

i checked sql query, i copied with fwrite in a txt file and it works fine...but i dont know why jqgrid doesnt display anything, it display columns and tne nam eof that but it's doesnt shoe the cells.............please help me.....i really dont know what i should do ....

Comment: `var id = $userId;` at the top of the script looks suspicious. It will throw an error unless $userId is defined in another `<script>...</script>` higher up the page. Or should the line be `var id = <%php echo $userId; %>;`?

Comment: thanks for responsing..i didnt copy top of this code... actually this script is between a php code and execute with echo...you know..for example : 

<?php 
echo "<script></script>";
?>
and userid define in top, in php file ....this code work in my localhost fine...but i dont know why doesnt work in server...

Comment: I agree, it's a mystery. Could be the url path? Does the directory structure on the server correctly mirror the structure on localhost?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am almost certain that it is the url value isn't correct. The url return the JSON data through Ajax call. It's not easy to debug in the past...until there's Firebug.

In Firefox use Firebug (press F12) and click on "Console" tab, then refresh your page. Take a look at the data returned in the Console. If it's not a valid JSON or it's a 404 error, then you know what to do next.

I only know how to do this in Firefox, I can't find equivalence in Google Chrome or IE Developer Toolbar. Hope this helps.